# C++ STL functional equivalents for metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std, sfinae

Are there constexpr or other compile time equivalents to the STL functional and other libraries for use with metaprogramming? More specifically, I am trying to write some metaprograms that use SFINAE to evaluate some conditional and generate the corresponding types. Example:

```
template<int A, int B>
enable_if_t<(A < B)> my_func() {// do something 
}

template<int A, int B>
enable_if_t<!(A < B)> my_func() {// do nothing 
}
```

Ideally I would like the user to be able to pass in a comparator (like `std::less<int>`), rather than hard coding it to `<`. So something like:

```
template<int A, int B, class comp = std::less<int>>
enable_if_t<comp(A, B)> my_func() {// do something 
}

template<int A, int B, class comp = std::less<int>>
enable_if_t<comp(A, B)> my_func() {// do nothing 
}
```

However since the functional objects are not constant expressions, they are not getting evaluated at compile time and so this does not work. What would be the right way to implement something like this?

Comment: `enable_if_t<comp{}(A, B)>`?

Comment: That doesn't work. The compiler complains: non-type template
      argument is not a constant expression

Comment: `enable_if_t` is only defined in [c++14](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). How do you expect it to work with c++11 ? Did you define it yourself ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::less<int>(int, int)` is not a constructor for `std::less`.  The only constructor for `std::less` is `()` (I prefer using `{}`, because it makes it clear I'm constructing something).

Since C++14 it has a `constexpr` `operator()` that (if `<` on the types involved is `constexpr`) can be evaluated at compile time.

Thus:

```
template<int A, int B, class comp = std::less<int>>
enable_if_t<comp{}(A, B)> my_func() {// do something 
}

template<int A, int B, class comp = std::less<int>>
enable_if_t<!comp{}(A, B)> my_func() {// do nothing 
}
```

should work.

In C++11

```
namespace notstd {
  template<class T=void>
  struct less {
    constexpr bool operator()(T const& lhs, T const& rhs)const{
      return lhs<rhs;
    }
  };
  template<>
  struct less<void> {
    template<class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator()(T const& lhs, U const& rhs)const{
      return lhs<rhs;
    }
    // maybe also add this:
    //struct is_transparent {};
  }
}
```

(assuming your `<` on your system is a total order on pointers) should work (replacing `std::less<T>` with `notstd::less<T>`).

Comment: Sorry, just updated the original question, I still have to be on C++11.

Comment: And if you're stuck with C++11, you can still define your own `constexpr` comparison functions/functors/whatever... :-)

Comment: the latter should be negated, `!comp{}(A, B)`

Comment: @AmmarHusain C++11 `notstd::less` implementation added.